# Drupal 7 using views adding page SQL error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a view in drupal 7 where I am trying to add another page. I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'data' at row 1: INSERT INTO {ctools_object_cache} (sid, obj, name, data, updated) VALUES ...etc...
```

It seems the blob data type is too small for the data being stored....If I change ctools_object_cache->data column to LONGBLOB, it works. But is this the best way to fix this?

Comment: You're pouring 5 gallons of water into a 5oz cup, and want to know if making the cup bigger is not the best solution?

Comment: Well I am just asking what the solution is. It would seem things like my scenario is pretty common with drupal views....It just breaks...

Comment: @MarcB: Its a pretty reasonable question in the context of Drupal to be honest

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially run into problems when you update the ctools module if you just change the field schema directly in the database. If ctools makes any changes to that column it could end up trying to make it the old size and you may end up losing data.

As well as changing the database field it would be a good idea to patch `ctools_schema()` (in the module's `.install` file) and change the column to a `LONGBLOB` there. Then when a new version of ctools comes out you can upgrade as normal, and re-patch the install file if you need to (bear in mind that this issue may have been reported on the module's issue queue and a similar fix may have been applied in an `update` hook in the ctools module; you should have a look at the `.install` file of the new version before updating to make sure).